# How to remove constraints from all subviews inside my superview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, nslayoutconstraint

I have a UIView that contains multiple UIView subviews that has its own constraints. How do I remove the subviews' constraints?

```
//only removes the constraints on self.view
[self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];

//I get warning: Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSArray *' to parameter of type 'NSLayoutConstraint'
[self.subview1 removeConstraints:self.subview1.constraints];
```

Comment: How do you **add** the constraints for `subview1`?

Comment: They were added in storyboard. I need to programmatically remove them.

Comment: Is `subview1` a direct descendent of `self.view`?

Comment: How do I check that? In storyboard, I just dragged a UIView into my view controller(superview) and applied some constraints to it.

Comment: Sounds like it is, then. Basically, in the Storyboard, if `subview1` is directly underneath `View`, then it's a direct descendent. Posting a possible answer now.

Comment: Removing constraints doesn't do much by itself. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @jrturton I agree. I assume he's trying to remove a particular view and can't do so while the constraints are still installed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this code:

```
for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in self.view.constraints) {
    if (constraint.firstItem == self.subview1 || constraint.secondItem == self.subview1) {
        [self.view removeConstraint:constraint];
    }
}
```

Basically, this iterates all of the constraints that are assigned to `self.view` and checks to see whether `self.subview1` is involved in the constraint. If so, that constraint gets pulled.

Comment: What does firstItem and secondItem do? What if I have 10 subviews? I have to check all them inside the forin loop?

Comment: An `NSLayoutConstraint` is a relationship between a view and either 0 (zero) or 1 other views. `firstItem` is the "first" item/view in the constraint relationship. If it exists, `secondItem` is the other item/view in the constraint relationship.

Comment: The code seems to remove only the constraints that's applied on subview1 by the superview(which [self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints] takes care of) and not the constraints thats INSIDE of subview1. Any idea how to remove the constraints inside of subview1?

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize `subview1` was also a container. I would expect `[self.subview1 removeConstraints:self.subview1.constraints]` to take care of that for you. Does it?

Comment: It doesn't, I get a warning:Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSArray *' to parameter of type 'NSLayoutConstraint'. When I run, it crashed with error:*** Assertion failure in -[UIView _removeConstraint:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:673
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: [constraint isKindOfClass:[NSLayoutConstraint class]]'
 Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you have typed `[self.subview1 removeConstraints:` and not `[self.subview1 removeConstraint:`? Make sure the "s" is there.

Comment: OMG, adding the "s" fixed the problem. Thanks a lot! Can't believe a single "s" would cause me so much trouble.

Comment: And the funny part is that you **have** the "s" in your question!

Comment: Yeah, I typed it instead of copy & paste. I should double check whatever I copy & paste now.

Comment: I see you accepted my answer. Would you mind giving me an upvote?

Comment: Sorry, it seems that upvoting requires at least 15 reputation and I only have 6. I'll definitely upvote when I have enough reputation.

Comment: Gotcha. Didn't realize you were so new here. Welcome!

Answer (score 5):

You have to remove all the constraints of the view and its subview. So create an extension of UIView and then define the following method:

```
extension UIView {
    func removeAllConstraints() {
        self.removeConstraints(self.constraints)
        for view in self.subviews {
            view.removeAllConstraints()
        }
    }
}
```

then call the following:

```
self.view.removeAllConstraints()
```

As answering later, This is in swift. This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an extension on UIView:

```
extension UIView{

    func removeConstraintsFromAllEdges(of view: UIView){

        for constraint in constraints{
            if (constraint.firstItem.view == view || constraint.secondItem?.view == view){
                removeConstraint(constraint)
            }
        }
    }

    func addConstraintsToAllEdges(of view: UIView){
        let leading = leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor)
        let top = topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor)
        let trailing = trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
        let bottom = bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([leading, top, trailing, bottom])
    }
}
```

Interesting note is `secondItem` is an optional property of [`NSLayoutConstraint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nslayoutconstraint) while `firstItem` is non-optional. Why? Because sometimes you may need to constrain a view's height to a constant value, so you there is no *other* view involved.

Answer (score 0):

I took @Honey's answer and modified it to work so a view can remove the constraints in relation to his superview.

```
extension UIView{

    func removeConstraintsFromAllEdges(){

        if let superview = superview {

            for constraint in superview.constraints{

                if let firstItem = constraint.firstItem, firstItem === self {
                    superview.removeConstraint(constraint)
                }

                if let secondItem = constraint.secondItem, secondItem === self {
                    superview.removeConstraint(constraint)
                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```