# Wrong cell frame when collectionView animation is coupled with another view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

as the title suggests, I'm going to illustrate the minimum needed to reproduce my situation.

I've got my FakeViewController embedded in Navigation Controller. It contains:

- a top view and a collectionView created on storyboard (please refer to image for constraints)
- a search controller assigned to navigationItem in code with `hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true`.

The cell must occupy the entire collectionView bounds (like a pageViewController) and it displays a simple viewController.view (the light blue one in picture).

At viewDidLoad everything is fine. When I tap the searchBar, the navigation bar disappears and either top view and collectionView move up.

BUT when I tap on cancel button, the cell remains a bit under the top view hiding part of its content.

The console prints:

```
The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fefc6463b10>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x7fefc78a2000; frame = (0 180; 375 438); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x604000a48fd0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60400022df20>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {375, 484}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fefc6463b10>.

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
```

Looking at the debug view Hierarchy, I found that collectionView has the right frame while its cell doesn't update it.
I don't how to force the cell turning shorter: tried whit a custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout or calling `invalidateLayout()` after cancel tapped happened but the problem persists.

EDIT: I forgot to say that topView is "required" to have the issue

Here my FakeViewControlelr implementation:

```
class FakeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {

//MARK: - Model
private var views = [UIView]()

//MARK: Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
private var searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupSearchController()
    setupCollectionView()
}

//MARK: - Helpers
private func setupSearchController() {
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search here"
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
}

private func setupCollectionView() {
    guard let supersetListVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SupersetListVC") else {return}
    self.addChildViewController(supersetListVC)
    self.views.append(supersetListVC.view)
    self.collectionView.delegate = self
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}

//MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return views.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let displayedView = self.views[indexPath.row]
    cell.contentView.addSubview(displayedView)
    displayedView.frame = cell.contentView.bounds
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    //NOTICE: this method isn't called when navigationBar turns visible.
    //Thats why I implemented searchBarCancellButtonClicked(_:)
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: collectionView.bounds.height)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

}

Thanks in advance for any help!
Kind regards
Alessandro

[image: constraints]

[image: viewDidLoad]

[image: search tap]

[image: cancel tap]

Comment: Just to be sure: avoid using frames. Just use constraints. pin the `displayView` to all 4 sides of the view like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47700868/5175709) and if you do such don't forget to set `displayView`'s `translatesautoresizingmaskintoconstraints` to `false`

Comment: @Honey I deleted `displayedView.frame = cell.contentView.bounds` in favor of constraints but nothing (also `translatesautoresizingmaskintoconstraints = false`). I believe that your suggestion affects cell.contentView and its subviews while I need to manage the cell layout somehow